# Javascript Injection through mailto:

Tags: javascript, forms, code-injection

Let's say that I have a form field in my HTML and its `name` property is `message`. Into this form, the user will (is supposed to) enter a body of an email. This email will then be sent from the browser with Javascript. The way I am accomplishing this is using `window.open()` on a `mailto:` string.

```
function validateAndSend(form) {
    var body = form.message.value;

    window.open("mailto:email@example.com?body=" + body);
}
```

This approach is working for me but I am concerned about its safety. I have heard about SQL-Injection, **and am wondering if the same thing applies to my situation.**

Is it possible for a malicious user to enter something into the form field that will cause harm such as

- Theft of any kind of information
- Executing their own Javascript code

**What I have tried**

- I have added checks before the email is sent to see if the text field
  contains at least one character as to avoid high high volumes of spam
  emails.
- Several test cases where I add various `<script>` tags to the input text in attempt to run my own code through the input. These malicious scripts simply show up in the body of the email, not affecting anything.

Am I vulnerable to Javascript Injection through the use of a `mailto:`?

Comment: From your example, the only thing the user would be able to do by modifying the source is change the populated values in their default mail application that will be started by the browser. Other than that,  I don't see how validating in the web form serves any purpose since the validation will not be present in their mail application.

Answer (score 0):

The `mailto:` will simply load the default handler for that protocol as defined by the OS/browser with the body specified. This ends up being no different than them sending you an email with the contents directly.

Since you talk about the malicious scripts still showing up in the body of the emails you have attempted to cleanse, I think you're more concerned with someone sending that to you directly and are deep enough into your current problem that you're forgetting anyone can send you that very same email at anytime... :-)